# Is there a library for loading in SVG layers to an Mac OS X application using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, interface

I want to use the SVG format for theming my game ui using Objective-C. The problem is the existing framework that would do everything I need (loading in specific SVG layers by their name, being very accurate) does not build for some reason with the following errors:

> ## Warnings
>
> Implicit declaration of function 'NSStringFromCGRect' is invalid in C99
>
> ## Errors
>
> _NSStringFromCGRect", referenced from:
> -[SVGDocument parseAttributes:] in SVGDocument.o
> Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> Clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have no idea what either of these mean, but it is safe to say it makes this unusable.

I found another solution in the form of a game on [gottcode](http://gottcode.org/cutemaze/); the only problem with this as you will probably see is that it uses the QT framework, not Objective-C.

- Is it possible to fix `SVGKit` so that the framework compiles?
- Is it possible to port Qsvg?

If the answer to either the questions is yes, then please point me in the right direction.

I managed to find a working one with help in one of the comments but the output has a green tint to it. Does anyone know what could cause this? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSStringFromCGRect` is one of the UIKit additions to Core Graphics, so it's likely you've tried to build an iOS-oriented library. That particular method isn't very hard to rewrite but it sounds like you might just have made some sort of selection error somewhere, as [the Git repository](https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit) for SVGKit seems to show a Mac target. I grabbed a copy from there (using the [download as .tar.gz link](https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit/tarball/master)), opened that in Xcode and hit build for 'My Mac 64-bit' and received four warnings but compilation completed.

Comment: I had seen that particular build but if you take a look at the SVGTester project you will see that the generated images have a layer of green over them. Not sure what's causing it

Answer (score 0):

SVGKit has *almost* support for OS X - but the focus is on getting the core library up to full SVG Spec compliance, and nearly everyone working on it is using iOS only.

So ... there's a few places where people have accidentally used iOS-only libraries (although we've been ironing most of those out on the new branch here: https://github.com/adamgit/SVGKit/tree/transforms - but that branch is currently "in development").

If you get build errors with a current SVGKit version, it usually means you just need to put an #if build switch for IOS around each error, and replace it with the identical OS-X only method (usually the same name, but using "NS" instead of "UI")